# Performing double press on button with code (8051)

Tags: c, button, atmel, 8051

With 8051 Microcontroller, button that connected to P3_2.
when I do:

```
 if(P3_2==1){ //One pressed button 
      //** Some LCD functions**//
    }
```

all good!

My thing is I want to get some others function when I 'Double Press' the button, But I don't know what is the code for

```
if(/*Perform double press*/){
   //** Some others LCD functions**//
 }
```

of course I use C code language for 8051.
any idea? What is the code for the second if?

Comment: Most likely you need a counter variable to count number of presses. And maybe a timer to abandon presses with too long intervals.

Comment: For simplicity you may write an another if withing your parent `if(P3_2==1){ if(P3_2==1){ //some code}`

Comment: Hey, wondering where you buy the 8051 and external board?